# Where can I find city/town boundaries in UK?

Tags: uk

Specifically, I am looking for the boundary of Barrow-in-Furness, a city in Cumbria, UK. GIS data in any format is preferable, but a scanned map with a clear boundary is also acceptable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to the [UK OpenData products site](https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/opendatadownload/products.html) and scroll down to the BoundaryLine dataset, this includes a GIS data download.

Additional data sources can be found through this [GIS StackExchange question from 2010](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/495/free-administrative-boundaries-available-as-shapefiles-for-united-kingdom-new-z).